# How can I highlight only few cells of a line in a table while hovering that line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developping my web application and I have a table in HTML within I want to higlight some cells of a line while hovering that line with the mouse. I do not want to highlight all of the cells of the line but I do not neither want to highlight a single cell.

```css
.line th[target=yes]:hover{
    background-color: #111;
}
```

It highlights cell by cell...

```css
.cell:hover{
    background-color: #111;
}
```

It also highlights cell by cell...

```
.line:hover{
    background-color: #111;
}
```

It highlights the whole line...

```html
<tr class="line">
   <th class="round" target='yes'></th>
   <th class="round" target='yes'>OF</th>
   <th class="round cell" target='yes'>Start Date</th>
   <th class="round cell" target='yes'>End date</th>
   <th class="round cell" target='yes'>Status</th>
</tr>
```

I only want to higlight cells of the class "cell".

Comment: `.line:hover .cell` … you really only have to translate what you want literally: Select all `.cell` that are descendants of the hovered `.line` …

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and effective response !

Answer (score 2):

You really only have to translate what you want literally: Select all `.cell` elements that are descendants of the hovered `.line`:

```
.line:hover .cell { /* … */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting the .cell class through its parent, here is how:

```css
.line:hover .cell{
  background-color: #111;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work (here and in your page), you need to wrap a table around it.

A `th` on its own is voodoo magic.

```css
.line:hover .cell{
background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="line">
    <th class="round" target="yes"></th>
    <th class="round" target="yes">OF</th>
    <th class="round cell" target="yes">Start Date</th>
    <th class="round cell" target="yes">End date</th>
    <th class="round cell" target="yes">Status</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line .cell:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="line">
     <th class="round" target='yes'></th>
     <th class="round" target='yes'>OF</th>
     <th class="round cell" target='yes'>Start Date</th>
     <th class="round cell" target='yes'>End date</th>
     <th class="round cell" target='yes'>Status</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```